# Javascript lightbox won't function inside a html section tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

[Above is with section tag and below is without](https://i.stack.imgur.com/we30k.png)I need to have the lightbox inside the section tag. Just not sure as to why this is happening or how to override this. The lightbox is appearing but it will not close and is behind the image. Here is the code:

```
 <section id="XXX">
 <div id="light" class="white_content">This is the lightbox content. <a href         = "javascript:void(0)" onclick =   "document.getElementById('light').style.display='none';document.getElementById(' fade').style.display='none'">Close</a></div>
<div id="fade" class="black_overlay"></div>


  <a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'">
                    <img src="Image.jpg" alt="Image" height="256" width="300">
                    </a>

 </section>
```

Nothing In the CSS indicates that there's an issue there...

```
       .black_overlay{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    z-index:1001;
    -moz-opacity: 0.8;
    opacity:.80;
    filter: alpha(opacity=80);
}
.white_content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 25%;
    left: 25%;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    padding: 16px;
    border: 16px solid orange;
    background-color: white;
    z-index:1002;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: That code runs.... what is the rest of the code?

Comment: Hope my edits help in some way

Answer (score 0):

The console reads:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null

Looking at your code

```
getElementById(' fade').
               ^^
```

Learn to use the developer console so you can find these typos.

```css
.black_overlay {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  z-index: 1001;
  -moz-opacity: 0.8;
  opacity: .80;
  filter: alpha(opacity=80);
}
.white_content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 25%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  padding: 16px;
  border: 16px solid orange;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 1002;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<section id="XXX">
  <div id="light" class="white_content">This is the lightbox content. <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.getElementById('light').style.display='none';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'">Close</a>
  </div>
  <div id="fade" class="black_overlay"></div>


  <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'">
    <img src="Image.jpg" alt="Image" height="256" width="300">
  </a>

</section>
```

Comment: When I copied the code over it made that space..I should've doubled checked. But it turns out that's not why it's causing this error.

Comment: So the code runs... so what is the CSS on the section tag. Maybe it is a z-index thing?

Comment: Wow...I want to punch myself in the face. I didn't think it had anything to do with the id inside the section tag...but it does. Will come back with more info.

Comment: yep..z-index issue. Taken care of. Thanks for the cross-checking help though!